# Working with Breeze + ViewModels

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, breeze

In my app I have my domain layer and web interface (other layers I will not go into details).

My views, working with ViewModels objects, and the database persist domain objects.
To convert a ViewModel object to a domain object I use AutoMapper.

The problem with the working Breeze is that when I will create a new object `var newCust = manager.createEntity('Customer', {name:'Beta'})` this is a domain object, and should be an ViewModel object.

Not all, but in some cases the ViewModel is not similar to the object domain. For example, collections of objects in the domain are: `ICollection<Person>` while in view model are `ICollection<int>` int is a PK of person.

#### Question

How to working with breeze in these cases?
How to make the metadata also manages the structure of my viewmodels so I can create objects of type my ViewModel?

Comment: ViewModels and domain objects are not the same. ViewModels may and often do expose domain objects. You may use a framework like durandal.js to handle view-viewmodel composition (and a lot more).

Comment: So? I never said they are the same!
The question is how work with Breeze and ViewModels.   In Breeze metadata only define domain objects. I need create ViewModel objects!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ridermansb - Because you mentioned AutoMapper, I will assume that your mapping is taking place on the server. You want your server API to expose "ViewModels" (in this case you might call them DTOs) rather than the domain model objects. Sometimes your ViewModels mirror your domain objects exactly; sometimes they don't.

Your client only sees what your API exposes. If this is a BreezeJS client, you will likely treat the ViewModels as client-side entities. They are Breeze entities in the sense that you expect Breeze to query, cache, change-track, and validate them.  BreezeJS doesn't know whether these "entities" correspond to server-side DTOs or server-side business objects.

Of course if you're using DTOs/ViewModels, your server code is responsible for translating between the DTO form and the domain object form. Presumably this logic lies somewhere in/between the server-side API layer and the domain layer.

If you have chosen this architecture, you have chosen to deal with the bi-directional translation between ViewModels and domain objects and have embraced all the complexity and hassle that entails. I have no words of advice for you on that score.

So let me rephrase and narrow your question: "How can I get metadata that describe the object model exposed by my server-side API?"

My favorite way (assuming a .NET server) is to let EF do it for me. I create a DbContext that references NOT my domain model classes but rather my ViewModel/DTO classes. Of course these classes would not actually map to a real database. No problem; they don't have to. You will never use this DbContext to access data. You will only use it to generate metadata. You are using EF as a design-time, metadata-generating tool ... and that's it. This is an efficient maintainable approach.

I hope to demonstrate this technique "soon" but I've been mighty busy recently so no promises.

Alternatively, you can write the metadata by hand [as described here](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/breeze-metadata-format).

Comment: I do not know how this approach would fit in my architecture.
About "classes would not actually map to a real database" this can bring various problems, not know if agree with this, would break some features of EF like migrations.

Comment: Why should that happen? What migrations? You use migrations with a database. There is no database associated with this "MetadataDbContext". It is simply a vehicle for describing an "entity model" that EF+Breeze.NET can turn into metadata. There is no "architecture" involved. Again ... we're talking about mapping your DTOs ... mapping them to nowhere.

Comment: Scaffold uses "DbSet <T>" to generate the migrations of the EF, or am I mistaken? As you said, not always DTOs are copies of the domain entities.
Does not seem right to use DbContext with DTOs. (I use I EF6 CodeFirst)
In my opinion using DbContext with DTOs for the breeze generates metadata of these entities do not seem right.

Comment: Another detail is that DbContext is in a repository layer, DTOs/ViewModels is an interface layer which prevents this approach

Comment: I think you are confusing production with design time tooling. There is NO ARCHITECTURE ISSUE. There are no practical impediments. You're already using EF anyway so you can't say you hate EF. Ignore scaffolding. Ignore migrations. Generate the metadata string, export it to file (it makes a nice JSON javascript file, e.g. "metadata.js"), and load it on your SPA shell web page. Stop worrying about purity and you'll sleep better . :-)

Comment: Ok :) very thanks .. ie a solution.
Although having to do this every time I create a new ViewModel/Dto be complicated, but it is a solution.  

We were doing a test with breeze to deploy with our webapp to improve performance and add additional simplicity. But this has become quite costly and the fact does not support many to many relationships hinders rather then chose to abandon breeze for a while., Despite believing to be a great tool.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Come back soon :-)

Comment: Ward, did you get a chance to create an example using this technique?  How would you use the SaveChanges in the BreezeController using the technique described above?  If I have custom DTOs would I need to create a SaveDtoName for each DTO that was created instead of one SaveChanges that saves directly to the database when using the Database's DbContext directly?

Comment: OK, so I made some progress on this that I will share in this comments in case anyone is trying to implement the suggestion given in this answer.  First you will need to create a DBContext that is not backed by database tables.  See http://www.debugrelease.com/2010/11/10/creating-entity-data-model-without-a-database-with-entity-framework-4/ for instructions on how to do that.  I am using EF 5.0 but the instructions are pretty much the same.  Creating entities for your EDM seems to be easier in 5.0 once you have it created.  Continued in next comment...

Comment: The next thing you will notice is that the call to _contextProvider.Metadata() (in BreezeController Metadata() Get Web Service) requires an entry in the web.config to be work without an actual connection to a database.  The following worked for me (adjust for the name of your EDM accordingly).      <add name="VisageViewModelContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/VisageViewModel.csdl|res://*/VisageViewModel.ssdl|res://*/VisageViewModel.msl;
         provider=System.Data.SqlClient; 
         provider connection string = 'Data Source=.;'"
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: See also the Breeze documentation on this topic: [Entity Framework as a metadata design tool](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/ef-design-tool).